# How to perform sql join on Dictionary<string,List<string>>?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

DictA is a string,string but DictB is a string,List(string)

The below worked for two dictionaries of strings without lists, but how do I join a dictionary with a list?

```
from kvp2 in DictB
join kvp3 in DictA on kvp2.Value equals kvp3.Key
where kvp2.Key == prim_in.ToUpper() || kvp2.Key == ref_in.ToUpper()
select new {Column1 = kvp2.Key, Column2 = kvp2.Value, column3 = kvp3.Value};
```

This works for a single value of the list, and although I could use a for loop to iterate through the length of that list, I'd really like to union back on itself each time. (changed kvp2.Value to kvp2.Value[0])

```
from kvp2 in DictB
join kvp3 in DictA on kvp2.Value[0] equals kvp3.Key
where kvp2.Key == prim_in.ToUpper() || kvp2.Key == ref_in.ToUpper()
select new {Column1 = kvp2.Key, Column2 = kvp2.Value[0], column3 = kvp3.Value};
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include the SQL structure, sample data for the dictionary, sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Since you're not including any databases in your LINQ query this really has nothing to do with SQL.  This is a pure LINQ to Objects question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the extended join I think you are after in a complete example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var DictB = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
    var DictA = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    DictB.Add("abc", new List<string>() {"123","456"});
    DictA.Add("456","foo");
    DictA.Add("123","bar");

    var res = from kvp2 in DictB
               from kvp2v in kvp2.Value
               join kvp3 in DictA 
               on kvp2v equals kvp3.Key
               select new {Column1 = kvp2.Key, Column2 = kvp2v, Column3 = kvp3.Value};

    foreach ( var item in res) Console.WriteLine(item);
  }

}
```

This produces the output

```
{ Column1 = abc, Column2 = 123, Column3 = bar }
{ Column1 = abc, Column2 = 456, Column3 = foo }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell if this is exactly what you're looking for. If you could include some examples of expected input/output that would be very helpful. If I've understood your question correctly, try this code.

```
var DictA = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var DictB = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

var query =
    (
        from b in DictB
        from a in DictA
            .Where(w => b.Value.Contains(w.Key))
        select new { C1 = b.Key, C2List = b.Value, C3 = a.Value }
    );

// SelectMany collapses the inner Select statement
var result = query.SelectMany(s => s.C2List.Select(s2 => new { C1 = s.C1, C2 = s2, C3 = s.C3 }));
```